# Show that $\xi(1/2 +it)$ is real.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\xi(s)=\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2)\zeta(s)$. Show that $\xi(s)$ is real valued if $s=\frac{1}{2}+it$.
I would like to show that $\overline{\xi\left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right)} = \xi\left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right)$ to prove this. If we had these two equalities $\overline{\xi(s)} = \xi(\overline{s})$ and $\xi(s)=\xi(1-s)$, then we would say
\begin{equation}
    \overline{\xi\left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right)} = \xi\left(\overline{\frac{1}{2}+it}\right) = \xi\left(\frac{1}{2}-it\right) = \xi\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{2}-it\right)\right) =\xi\left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right).
\end{equation}
However, I do not know why the two equalities hold. Could someone show me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second equality, $\xi(s)=\xi(1-s)$ is known as the functional equation of the Xi function. It can be proved either directly from the Riemann Zeta function functional equation:

$$
\zeta(s) = 2^s\pi^{s-1}\ \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\ \Gamma(1-s)\ \zeta(1-s)
\!,$$

using the definition of Xi as:

$$\xi(s) = \frac{1}{2}\pi^{-s/2}s(s-1)\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)\zeta(s)$$

[from Wikipedia - [Riemann Zeta Function]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function)

or from [Harold M. Edwards 'Riemann Zeta function', p.17](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=IpZjL5_EsI8C&pg=PA17#v=onepage&q&f=false) $(3)$, where letting $s=a+bi$ means $\xi(a+bi)=\xi(1-a-bi)$.

The first I'm not so sure about, however we can prove $\xi(\overline s)=\xi(s)$ from $(2)$ from the HME link. Following on from Riemann's version, we have that $\cos$ is an even function, and so the sign of $t$ can be ignored.